# Storing values in session or sessionstorage using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, session, session-storage

I am using jquery selectable and checkbox dropdown list for one of my page. I am using asp.net mvc code first and razor view engine. I have automatic page refresh every few seconds or minutes based on user's choice. 
I need to save selecteditems of jquery selectable and the checkbox dropdown list selections somewhere to bring the page back to its state even after the page refreshes. What is the best way to achieve this?
When the user selection changes, only then the storage must get refreshed with the new selections.
Please let me know which of session/ sessionstorage is a good approach. If this is not a good approach, is there any other way of achieving this other than using the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is really up to you where to store. [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) is a good option for that but you should be aware that < IE8 versions do not support that, so you should look into cross-browser solutions ([jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/), [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) and etc).

Alternatively, you can store that setting on your server as some of user settings, which will add some convenience to users of your app if they will access that from different devices. (however that will a bit increase data amount sending back a forth to a server).